# How to make GSP tag generate code on one line?

Tags: javascript, grails, gsp

I am dynamically adding a select box inside a div element with the following code:

```
$('#worker').html('<g:select class = "dropdown" name="worker" from="${workers}" optionKey="id" optionValue="name" />');
```

The problem with this code is that when the `g:select` tag expands, it will generate the code as follows:

```
    $('#worker').html('<select onchange="handleWorkerChange(this)" class="dropdown" name="worker" id="worker" >
<option value="2" >Worker1</option>
<option value="4" >Worker1</option>
<option value="18" >Worker1</option>
<option value="19" >Worker1</option>
</select>');
```

As you can see above, when expanding, the option tags are in new lines so this will cause syntax error in JavaScript. Is there a way so that the select `gsp` tag will expand to a single line string so that the select box can be embedded dynamically in a div?

Comment: I'm trying to understand how are you going to expand g:select tag on the client side. when you dynamically add g:select tag using js it wont expand, because g:select can be expanded only on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`g:select` is also available just as a [method within the GSP](http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Tags/select.html):

```
${select(from:aList,value:aValue)}
```

Taking advantage of this and the fact that then we are just dealing with a text (`org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.StreamCharBuffer`), we can remove the new line characters:

```
$('#worker').html('${ select(
    class: 'dropdown', 
    from: workers, 
    optionKey='id', 
    optionValue: 'name', 
    name: 'worker'
).replace(System.getProperty("line.separator"), '') }');
```

This should result in the entire select be placed on a single line.

---

Initially, I wasn't sure myself exactly what was causing the `select` being placed over several lines, so I went straight to the source: [FormTagLib](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/2.3.x/grails-plugin-gsp/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/taglib/FormTagLib.groovy).

Snippet from FormTagLib:

```
writer << "<select "
// process remaining attributes
outputAttributes(attrs, writer, true)

writer << '>'
writer.println()
```

As you can see, it's just a simple `println` method call:

> Terminates the current line by writing the line separator string. The line separator string is defined by the system property line.separator, and is not necessarily a single newline character ('\n').

This is why it's important to use `System.getProperty("line.separator")`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

you cannot `append` or `html` grails code like that.

you muse use html code.

```
var youComboboxCode = "<select><option>aaaa</option><option>bbb</option></select>";

$('#worker').html(youComboboxCode);
```

i will share my code

```
 var htmlcodeA = '';

if(data)
{
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     htmlcodeA = htmlcodeA + "<option value="+data[i].id+">"+data[i].purchaseNo+"</option>";
   }
}

$('#home').find('option').remove();
$('#home').html(htmlcodeA ).change();
```